# Google maps v3 api Map doesnt fully load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am building an app that will have maps showing nearby eateries.

Map shows up, but takes a very long time to load, and never actually fully loads.

I am on a deadline with this, and I've tried a variety of solutions with no luck.

Someone please help!!!

See code below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>Food & Drink</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
          type="text/javascript"></script>


<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 360px; height: 300px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = [
      ['Little Shebas', 39.833691, -84.892375, 1],
      ['Roscoes Coffee Bar & Tap Room', 39.833891, -84.892130, 2],
      ['Ullerys Homemade Icecream', 39.834401, -84.889190, 3],
       ['Firehouse BBQ and Blues', 39.833630, -84.891887, 4],
      ['Tin Lizzie Cafe', 39.829140, -84.890857, 6]
      ['Joes Pizza', 39.834409, -84.889822, 5],
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 25,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.830184, -84.893401),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Try using an initial zoom level below the max (like eleven or so) and see if that makes any difference in the loading.

Comment: Thanks Jared for your feedback. I changed it to 11. It loaded two little pieces of the map, but it doesn't show any markers, and seems to just sit there after initial load.

Comment: per antsernot, are you trying this on desktop or mobile?

Comment: Just refreshed the page, not shows markers, but still only showing small pieces of the map

Comment: That's your first problem :). Load it in a browser, and check out http://livereload.com/

Comment: Thank you Jared. That gives me a headache. I am a beginner, using Adobe Phone Gap and it was supposed to be soooo much more easier than it has been!!

Comment: Add a comma after the line with 'Tin Lizzie Cafe', and remove the one after the line with 'Joes Pizza'

Answer (score 1):

I cannot confirm the behavior you described. Everything seems to be working fine and your code looks like it should work.

Check out this [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/8qf3zt9n/) of your code. I played around with the inital zoom level and adjusted the center. The center you had specified wasn't really near the markers and the zoom level was so high at first I thought the map wasn't loading.

```
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(39.833691, -84.892375);

google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 15,
    center: center,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
```

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for! But when I change my center it doesn't display at all. I'm so confused!!!!

Comment: See my answer. Fix your array and set your initial zoom to 20. @James Taylor your example only partly works, js error and 4 markers instead of 6

Comment: I removed the 6th element, and changed the zoom. Now just coming to a grey map area, no content.

Comment: Yeah, definitely fix the comma problem in the array after this line: `['Tin Lizzie Cafe', 39.829140, -84.890857, 6]` although the trailing comma doesn't matter in JS. Could be only on my end, but the JS fiddle appears to be bugged out when editing the `center`. Just make sure whatever you make it appears in the form above. JS fiddle appears to be off by one character.

Comment: I've updated my answer, should have said 14 instead of 20, my bad. @James Taylor that trailing comma does indeed matter in older versions of IE

Comment: Ok, so after making changes, it seems to be loading...still haven't achieved anything like the working example above by James. Seems that it never quite loads fully. Thank you all for your feedback.

Comment: Do I need to just be more patient? Will it load like this once it is an app? This is def not the end result that the client is expecting....:/ Im so stressed!!!

Comment: Google maps is going to load slowly on mobile. It just is. You are not going to be able to produce an app using phonegap that has anywhere near the perf of google's native apps coded in java or c++

Comment: I don't think this would be end behavior. I've written very similar applications (albeit not using phonegap) and I've gotten good performance. Obviously, this is limited to the networks that your clients are using. If you are writing a specialized app for an area, you could conceivably look into overlaying cached map data if you think it will be a problem.

Comment: I really appreciate your help! But, I don't even know what that means....I created Fusion Tables for already existing maps, and couldn't figure that out.....Im beginning to think I should just make an map from an image and having it static! As I mentioned, I am on a time restriction, and Im really scared now being that I can't figure this out!!

Comment: So, is there a max of 5 marker that I can implement with this? I need several other maps, including one that would have est. 30 markers on it...

Comment: I've built google maps apps that had thousands of polylines and markers. There's no restriction beyond the amount of memory the browser/app has available to it. But, and I hate to be the bearer of bad news, google maps API is not free if you're developing commercial apps with it. They'll let you use it to experiment or do research but for commercial uses they (rightly) want to get paid.

Comment: Er. The app I'm writing right now has more than 5 markers and it's "free". I believe the way Google does it is based on 'views', not content. Check the Google developer console and be sure to register your application.

Comment: Yes I believe thats more or less correct. I've built 3 google maps apps for work as an experiment for internal use and we're debating whether to cough up the licensing fees to google or rewrite them using our own `gis` map layers. I'm *really* hoping they decide to go with google :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem in your array. Looking at the code in chrome dev tools it shows the locations array to contain 5 elements (not 6) the fifth of which is `undefined`. You're missing a comma after the 5th element and have a trailing comma after the last. Trying to access properties on that undefined element is throwing the javascript exception that's halting execution on the page. Also, at the initial zoom you have set nothing is visible. Zooming out reveals the map with your markers. Set your initial zoom in your map options to 14.